# Idiomatic way of finding by value predicate on a Map

Tags: kotlin

What is the best way to search a map and find the first key that matches a predicate on value or null otherwise? My code below looks too verbose for kotlin standard. Please help.

```
fun  <K, V> find(map : Map<K, V?>, predicate: (V?) -> Boolean): K? {
    var key : K? = null
    map.forEach { it ->
        if(predicate(it.value)) {
            key = it.key
            return@forEach
        }
    }
    return key
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
map.entries.firstOrNull { predicate(it.value) }?.key
```

`entries` is used to make the `Map` iterable, and is "free" (in that it doesn't require iterating over the map). Of course, it enables all collection extension functions missing on `Map` itself, not just `firstOrNull`.

(You can also replace `firstOrNull` with `find`; they are equivalent here.)

Comment: There are several reasonably good answers, but this is the shortest and easiest to read, and probably the most efficient.  So it gets my vote :-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `var key`, you can instead immediately return the key once found and `return null` in the end.

In the lambda passed to `forEach`, you can use parameter destructuring to access the key and value without using `it`:

```
fun  <K, V> find(map : Map<K, V?>, predicate: (V?) -> Boolean): K? {
    map.forEach { (key, value) ->
        if (predicate(value)) {
            return key
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

Also, you can convert the `map` parameter to receiver, making it an extension function that can be called on a map instance:

```
fun <K, V> Map<K, V>.findKeyByValue(predicate: (V) -> Boolean): K? {
    forEach { (key, value) ->
        if (predicate(value)) {
            return key
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

```
val result = myMap.findKeyByValue { it > 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of [`filter`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html) and [`firstOrNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/first-or-null.html)

```
val firstKey = map.keys.filter { it == 1 }.firstOrNull()
```

To make it lazy, convert it to a sequence before:

```
val firstKey = map.keys.asSequence().filter { it == 1 }.firstOrNull()
```

Comment: `predicate` needs to be applied on a value, not a key. (And such a combination can be replaced by calling `firstOrNull` with a lambda parameter.)

Comment: You are right. I missed that detail in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter for search a map and find the first key

for example

```
var arr = mutableMapOf<Any, Any>()
        arr.put("1", "dax1")
        arr.put("2", "dax2")
        arr.put("3", "dax3")
        arr.put("4", "dax4")

        val key = arr.filter {
            it.value.equals("dax5")
        }.keys
        if (key.isNotEmpty()) {
            Log.e("key", key.elementAt(0).toString())
        } else {
            Log.e("key", "Key not found")
        }
```

Hope this will help you